# php parse multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I have a simple 2D array

```
    Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [0] => 7
                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                        [0] => 7
                )

        [2] => Array
                (
                )
)
```

lets say this is called `$myArray` when i try parsing it by

```
$i = 0;
while( $i < count($myArray) ){
    $val = $myArray[$i][0];
    echo $val;
    $i++;
}
```

i get an error `Undefined offset: 0`

can anyone lend a hand please

Comment: Not all the sub-arrays have the index `0`. You need to check if the index `0` is set before trying to access it: `if (isset($myArray[$i][0])) { ... }`.

Comment: Looks like `$myArray[2]` is empty and has no `[0]` key

Comment: or you can use foreach instead of while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$i = 0;
while( $i < count($myArray) ){
    $val = current($myArray[$i]);
    echo $val;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're making assumptions about the shape of you're array. Assumptions can be dangerous.

If you give me an array, I can't just assume that it has an index 0. I would need to test for it first:

```
<?php echo isset($myArray[$i][0]) ? $myArray[$i][0] : ''; ?>
```

Checking with [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) is very handy.